# Extract subset of a string following specific text in R

Tags: regex, r, string, subset

I am trying to extract all of the words in the string below contained within the brackets following the word 'tokens' only if the 'tokens' occurs after 'tag(noun)'.

For example, I have the string:

```
m<- "phrase('The New York State Department',[det([lexmatch(['THE']),
inputmatch(['The']),tag(det),tokens([the])]),mod([lexmatch(['New York State']),
inputmatch(['New','York','State']),tag(noun),tokens([new,york,state])]),
head([lexmatch([department]),inputmatch(['Department']),tag(noun),
tokens([department])])],0/29,[])."
```

I want to get a list of all of the words that occur within the brackets after the word 'tokens' only when the word tokens occurs after 'tag(noun)'.

Therefore, I want my output to be a vector of the following:

```
[1] new, york, state, department
```

How do I do this? I'm assuming I have to use a regular expression, but I'm lost on how to write this in R.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want a single element or a vector of length 4?

Comment: I want to return a vector of length 4. I used G. Grotondieck approach below and used cbind to create a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove newlines and then extract the portion matched to the part between parentheses in pattern `pat`.  Then split apart such strings by commas and simplify into a character vector:

```
library(gsubfn)

pat <- "tag.noun.,tokens..(.*?)\\]"
strapply(gsub("\\n", "", m), pat, ~ unlist(strsplit(x, ",")), simplify = c)
```

giving:

```
[1] "new"        "york"       "state"      "department"
```

**Visualization:** Here is the debuggex representation of the regular expression in `pat`.  (Note that we need to double the backslash when put within R's double quotes):

```
 tag.noun.,tokens..(.*?)\]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Zji0uBFvWXoAWR_I)

Note that `.*?` means match the shortetst string of any characters such that the entire pattern matches - without the `?` it would try to match the longest string.

Comment: I grant thee an upvote for debuggex (thanks SO comment nazis). that's awesome.

Comment: Thank you! Works well! I was able to adapt your approach across a vector of strings that follow the same format.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this. Here i'll use the [regcatputedmatches](https://gist.github.com/MrFlick/10413321) helper function to make it easier to extract the captured matches.

```
m<- "phrase('The New York State Department',[det([lexmatch(['THE']),inputmatch(['The']),tag(det),tokens([the])]),mod([lexmatch(['New York State']),inputmatch(['New','York','State']),tag(noun),tokens([new,york,state])]),head([lexmatch([department]),inputmatch(['Department']),tag(noun),tokens([department])])],0/29,[])."

rx <- gregexpr("tag\\(noun\\),tokens\\(\\[([^]]+)\\]\\)", m, perl=T)
lapply(regcapturedmatches(m,rx), function(x) {
    unlist(strsplit(c(x),","))
})

# [[1]]
# [1] "new"        "york"       "state"      "department"
```

The regular expression is a bit messy because your desired match contains many special regular expression symbols so we need to properly escape them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one liner if you like:

```
paste(unlist(regmatches(m, gregexpr("(?<=tag\\(noun\\),tokens\\(\\[)[^\\]]*", m, perl=T))), collapse=",")
[1] "new,york,state,department"
```

Broken down:

```
# Get match indices
indices <- gregexpr("(?<=tag\\(noun\\),tokens\\(\\[)[^\\]]*", m, perl=T)

# Extract the matches
matches <- regmatches(m, indices)

# unlist and paste together
paste(unlist(matches), collapse=",")
[1] "new,york,state,department"
```

Comment: I used strsplit to vectorize the string output into a list of nouns:        strsplit(paste(unlist(regmatches(m, gregexpr("(?<=tag\\(noun\\),tokens\\(\\[)[^\\]]*", m, perl=T))), collapse=","),",")